# Get Wordpress PostID with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cordova

I'm making a Cordova app and I need to get a wordpress website's postIDs. I've done some research and found that I should use the built-in url_to_postid function. However, since this is a cordova app I am unable to run PHP.

Is there a way to get a postID via Javascript? I have the article URLs from the website's RSS feed, so I can grab them if they are of any help.

I was thinking of using the URL and requesting the postID from the page, however, I'm not sure how to do that, if it's even possible.

Comment: How's your targeted wordpress urls look like? You might be able to replicate function [url_to_postid](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/)'s first few lines into JS to directly grab the postid. It is just a regex url match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to interact with a WP instance from a cordova app, then perhaps you should look into connecting to the WP instance via the REST API to get those kind of details.

See: http://v2.wp-api.org/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I accept this answer because it will work for my application as well as in general for other people's applications. I also posted the solution I used as an answer because it's a pretty specific example.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the PostID due to the access to the website's RSS feed. I missed the fact that there was a  tag that had the URL with the ?p=postID. I then simply parsed the ID out of the string within guid.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass PHP value to Javascript by using [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

**In functions.php**

```
<?php
global $post;
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$data_array = array(
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'my_data', $data_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

**In myscript.js**

```
<script>
// alerts post_id
alert( my_data.post_id);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this will help with getting that information to a Cordova app as per the question.